# Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$ is differentiable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$ is differentiable in its domain, i.e. 
$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0)} \frac{|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0} + \frac{1}{y_0^2}(y - y_0)|}{||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)||}=0$

I tried this: 
$|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0} + \frac{1}{y_0^2}(y - y_0)| = |y - y_0|(|\frac{1}{y_0^2}-\frac{1}{y_0y}|) \leq ||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| (|\frac{1}{y_0^2}-\frac{1}{y_0y}|)$

Let $\delta = \frac{y_0}{2}$
Then $|y - y_0| < \frac{y_0}{2}$
$\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{y_0^2} < \frac{1}{y_0^2} - \frac{1}{y_0y} < \frac{1}{3y_0^2}$

Then I do not know what to do

Comment: Could you not just as easily show that its partial derivatives exist and are continuous?

Comment: @cmk no, that does not imply differentiability

Comment: If the partial derivatives are continuous in a neighborhood, it certainly does.

Comment: The problem is that I have to prove it by definition.

Comment: @cmk ah okay sure, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{|y-y_0|\left|\frac{1}{y_0^2}-\frac{1}{y_0y}\right|}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}\leq \frac{|y-y_0|\left|\frac{1}{y_0^2}-\frac{1}{y_0y}\right|}{|y-y_0|}=\left|\frac{1}{y_0^2}-\frac{1}{y_0y}\right|\rightarrow 0$$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (x,y_0),$ provided $y_0\neq 0.$ Now, just use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\colon U\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function on some subset $U\subset\mathbb R$, then $g\colon \mathbb R\times U \to \mathbb R$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto f(y)$ is as well:

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(y)-f(y_0)-f'(y_0) (y-y_0)}{\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|}
&=
\Bigg(\underbrace{\frac{f(y)-f(y_0)}{y-y_0}-f'(y_0)}_{\to0}\Bigg)\cdot\underbrace{\frac{y-y_0}{\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|}}_{\left|\ \cdot\ \right|\le1}
\to 0.
\end{align*}

Hence, all you need to show is that $y\mapsto \frac{1}{y}$ is differentiable on its domain.